# MYSQL Select count with IF

Tags: mysql, select, count

I want get all users with a number of orders with division status

MY QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    users.id as "Id", 
    users.firstname as "Firstname", 
    users.lastname as "Lastname",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 0, 1, 0)) as "Status #0",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 1, 1, 0)) as "Status #1",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 2, 1, 0)) as "Status #2",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 3, 1, 0)) as "Status #3",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 4, 1, 0)) as "Status #4",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 5, 1, 0)) as "Status #5",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 6, 1, 0)) as "Status #6",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 7, 1, 0)) as "Status #7",
    COUNT(IF(orders.status = 8, 1, 0)) as "Status #8"
FROM 
    users 
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.idu = users.id 
WHERE 
    users.register_complete = 1 
GROUP BY 
    users.id 
ORDER BY 
    users.date_register DESC
```

Result:
[image]

All status is to same.... where is problem?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Change COUNT to SUM and you are done!

Comment: Use Sum instead of using Count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count(value)` will count as `1` if `value` is something else than `null`, see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> **COUNT(expr)**
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.

So you counted every row, independent from your `IF`-condition.

Either change your `count` into `sum`, or change `0` into `null` to get the desired result:

```
...
COUNT(IF(orders.status = 0, 1, null))
...
```

Comment: Great news! Thanks you!

Comment: note `sum(IF(orders.status = 0, 1, 0))` will return null instead of 0 if there are no rows matching the where conditions, which is probably not what you want. So I recommend using `count()`